Realistic lightining on a door
I need to replicate a door in Unity.
This is my 3d model reference:

As you can see the lighting is very "neutral" and the color is uniform. Perfect.
Using the same 3D model but with my own light, I obtain this effect:

The light is too hard, the color is "burned". I'm not able to replicate the the door like the reference.
Do you have any advice?

lighting is not really a programming question but your reference seems to be matt, it seems to have a generic overall light.. your unity has a spot light in what looks like 2 corners and is way more glossy
